# Change value of specific annotated fields of an object which is used as a type for multiple fields in some object - Jackson Object Mapper Serialize

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, objectmapper

I have a Person class:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private String address;
}
```

Now this Person class is used in another class as:

```
public class Group {
    private Person nicePerson;
    private Person badPerson;
    private Person secretPerson;
}
```

Now, I want to serialize my Group object to JSON using Jackson ObjectMapper. I'm using a custom serializer based on some annotation.

When I serialize the Group object, I'm looking for the following output:

```
{
    "nicePerson": {
        "name": "John",
        "address": "usa"
    },
    "badPerson": {
        "name": "Harold",
        "address": "canada"
    },
    "secretPerson": {
        "name": "XXXXXXX",
        "address": "london"
    }
}
```

Here, I want to change the name of 'secretPerson' to "XXXXXXX".

But I'm having some problems.

I have made following annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD})
public @interface SecretInfo {
    String maskedValue = "XXXXXXX";
    String value() default maskedValue;
}
```

I have annotated my Person class following way:

```
public class Person {
    @SecretInfo
    private String name;
    private String address;
}
```

I have made the following serializer which looks for this annotation and then changes the value. It is using some generics now for convenience.

```
public class SecretInfoSerializer<T> extends StdSerializer<T> implements ContextualSerializer {

    private SecretInfo secretInfo;

    public SecretInfoSerializer() {
        super((Class<T>) String.class);
    }

    public SecretInfoSerializer(SecretInfo secretInfo,
                                          JavaType clazz) {
        super(clazz);
        this.secretInfo = secretInfo;
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(T value, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
        if (secretInfo != null && value != null) {
            jsonGenerator.writeString(secretInfo.value());
        } else jsonGenerator.writeString(getValue(value));
    }

    @Override
    public JsonSerializer<?> createContextual(SerializerProvider serializerProvider, BeanProperty property) {
        if (property != null) {
            return new SecretInfoSerializer<>(
                    property.getAnnotation(SecretInfo.class),
                    property.getType());
        } else {
            return new SecretInfoSerializer<>();
        }
    }

    private String getValue(T value) {
        if (value == null) {
            return "null";
        } else {
            return value.toString();
        }
    }

}
```

I have associated this with Annotation Introspector and made the ObjectMapper.
Then I serialized my 'Group' class above. But I get the following output:

```
{
    "nicePerson": {
        "name": "XXXXXXX",
        "address": "usa"
    },
    "badPerson": {
        "name": "XXXXXXX",
        "address": "canada"
    },
    "secretPerson": {
        "name": "XXXXXXX",
        "address": "london"
    }
}
```

As you can see, since I annotated the 'name' field in Person class, I'm getting "XXXXXXX" for every Person class there is. But this is not what I wanted. I just want to change the value for 'secretPerson' only.

I don't know what to do:

Maybe there is some way such as following:

```
public class Group {
    private Person nicePerson;
    private Person badPerson;
    @HasSecretInfo
    private Person secretPerson; 
}
```

Then the serializer would check if it `@HasSecretInfo`, only then look for `@SecretInfo` ...etc. something like this.

So I'm looking to solve this problem. If you have any solution, that'd be great.

Comment: Did you managed to find a solution for this?